# In PHP, when using PDO with pgSQL how to get the value of "RETURNING" clause in the original INSERT sql query

Tags: php, insert, pdo, postgresql

In PHP, I am using PDO with the pgSQL drivers. I wanted to know how to get the value of the "RETURNING" clause given in the INSERT sql query.
My current code looks like this,

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO "TEST" (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('John', 'Doe') RETURNING user_id';
$queryHandle = $connection->prepare($query);
$queryHandle->execute();
```

Obviously

> $queryHandle->execute();

returns TRUE or FALSE. But I wanted to get the value of "user_id" if the insert was successful. Can you guys give me a pointer as to how to go about it? Thanks.

Comment: I did try using PDO::lastInsertID first. But it was just returning blank values. Hence after looking around found that the above way is much cleaner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you tried to treat the command as a select returning, running

```
$ret=$queryHandle->fetchAll();
```

Comment: It definitely works! :) But I was hoping for a more direct/clean way to do this. Maybe I am asking for too much...

Comment: There is no cleaner way, as you have a returned data. It is trivial you have to fetch it.

Comment: k. Just a minor thing, I used fetch() instead of fetchAll() sine its guaranteed that there be only one insert at a time.

Answer (score 12):

```
$ret = $queryHandle->fetchColumn();
```

Will return a single value instead of an array.

Comment: This is the correct way if you just want to get the ID back `RETURNING id ...`

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it like this (PHP 8.1.13, PostreSQL 15):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('John', 'Doe') RETURNING id";
$queryHandle = $connection->prepare($query);
$queryHandle->execute();
$last_id = $connection->lastInsertId('test_id_seq');
```

I took 'test_id_seq' from the following SQL, i.e. it is [table]_[column]_seq

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.test
(...
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 'nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass)',
CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: What's wrong with simply doing $queryHandle->fetchColumn(); tho?